# how to format epoch time into YYYY-MM-DD mm:ss:(milliseconds) in python?

Tags: string, python-2.7, date, datetime

I have a bunch of epoch times, and I need to reformat them into YYYY-MM-DD mm:ss:(milliseconds).

basically it is the opposite of this post [How to convert a date in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to unix epoch time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654377/how-to-convert-a-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-to-unix-epoch-time)
.
I have tried a few different things, like doing string manipulations.  But, I feel like there must be an easier way.  using perhaps `datetime` or another library that is used for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400256/python-converting-epoch-time-into-the-datetime

Comment: Please stop calling it "epoch time" when you mean [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  There have been [many different epochs used in computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing).